# Creatiing Virtual RAM for a Virtual Machine

Tags: memory, virtual-machine

I have sort of been forced into a corner here.

I am setting up a "Promo" laptop to showcase software to clients. However, due to restrictions, I can only use one laptop to run this.

What I have done so far is installed Windows 2012 R2 on the laptop, however now I have been given additional software that can only run on a Client OS (Windows 7/10). The easy solution is to run a VM for the Client PC, however I'm restricted by the laptop's current specs - primarily the RAM.

- Laptop RAM: 8GB
- Windows 2012 R2 req: 2GB
- Windows 7 req: 2GB
- Total minimum requirements for all software to run: ~24GB (possibly more).

Fortunately, most of the requirements are placed by the Client software, so if I can create Virtual Memory (from an EHD perhaps?) for it to use, then problem solved. Is this possible in VMWare or Hyper-V?

Comment: Actually no I recommend virtualbox which is free.

Comment: There is a software to use if you have an SSD where you can use the SSD for RAM, but it is a paid software. Otherwise, there is not this capacity in Windows.

Comment: You can't create virtual memory that isn't a thing.  Creating a Cache drive won't add memory to the virtual machine.  There is no way to run software that requires  24GB of system memory on a system that only has 8GB.  Of course I realize you might be using "memory" in place of storage space. Specifics are lacking

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not have the ability to virtualize RAM. However, if you have an SSD, you can use any amount of the SSD to virtualize RAM using Primocache https://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-cache/

The only downside is you have to pay for the Primocache software. If it was free, I would be using it for more RAM on my PC.

When you said EHD, it looks like you meant External Hard Drive. If so, then with Primocache you can virtualize the RAM from an external SSD, but you can't do this in Windows natively.

Comment: Does windows Paging file not perform a function similar to emulating RAM? (-linuxuser)

Comment: No, it does not. Pagefile just stores temporary files, but does not increase actual RAM that for example could be used by a virtual machine. In order to have more "virtual" RAM, you need to emulate it. Paging is not the emulation he is looking for. Windows does not have native RAM emulation, probably because when Windows was developed, SSD did not exist. Instead, you need a specific RAM virtualization software that is designed to work with Windows, and the only one I know of is Primocache.

Answer (score 0):

There is no substitute for RAM. The operational and performance characteristics of an SSD, however fast, are completely different from RAM.

The Primocache software augments the system cache with an SSD. This can be useful but it does not add to RAM in any meaningful way.

If you really need 24 GB of RAM you need more RAM. There is no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

8 GB ram is enough to run virtual machine. You can set up virtual ram in main machine and in virtual machines in My Computer Left click -> Properties then Advanced, Advanced, Performance tab, Advanced, Virtual memory field, Button Change.

For 8gb ram you can put 8 gb virtual ram. Thats so much but will be enought already without virtual ram. Isnt it?

If setting system managed virtual memory then it will be slower but if

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWCVhk5gTps

Comment: Setting the page file, really? If That's your suggestion it won't help the author run 24GB of software on a VM with less then 24GB of physical memory

Comment: Why not? Elaborate. Im using virtual machines. Virtual machine make 10 or 15 GB and 4 GB virtual ram. Swap in linux is the same- a file where virtual memory stored. Here actually its not needed. 8 GB or ram.

Comment: You cannot assigned more memory to virtual machine then the amount of physical memory you have.  User wants to assign a virtual machine with more than 8GB of memory with only 8 GB of total memory.  I got rick rolled when I watched that video.

Comment: From where you got that he has 8GB HDD? OP said ram is 8GB not HDD. HDD is more since mentioned that totally disk space needed to run all is 24GB. Computer must have more then that since theres not problem in disk space. All is fine. What rickrolled? Link has video of how to set virtual memory! Virtual memory is using disk space as much as assigned in virtual memory settings.

Comment: I never said the author had a 8GB HDD.

Comment: Your previous comment you say that im wrong cause he cant put on 8G virtual. He can on PC on witch he will run VM.

Comment: I was refereeing to a virtual machine not virtual memory.  The amount of memory the author would need is 24 GB to run the VMs he wants to run.

Comment: Great for you. Jeezus. Thats good. So it will work. Just setting up VRam anything between 4GB and if not enought even double. And VM making with enought space 24 or 100GB divided for each system. Easy! OP already told that he needs 24 GB to run so no problem there but not needed to refer to it again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your setup will not work very well.  First off, Windows Server and Windows 7 will work with 2GB.  However, neither of those amounts of memory will be ideal, as the machine will page under heavy RAM usage.  If your client software truly needs 20GB of memory to run, then your laptop at worst, will not run the software.  At best, the software will run, but the machine will be paging so hard it would seem as if it is not running.  Windows allows you to run software that requires more memory than you have, however that causes the paging.

If you truly need 24+ GB of memory, your company should provide you a machine that can handle the software.